# Is there way to order by desc the format alias in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have problem regarding on order by and formatting of numbers if I use the order by function to the format alias it not works. I don't know why. to understand more well. I will show you my sample script that i made.

**Problem:** I can't sort the formatted alias.

**Script:**

```
 $true_gap_list_item = DB::select("SELECT 

        FORMAT((sum(a_cost- b_cost)),0) as ab,

        FROM cron_db.misreport_weekly_foodcost_item as mwfi
        WHERE mwfi.storeid IN(".$converted_selected_store.") AND year(mwfi.date) = year(subdate(curdate(),1))
        order by ab DESC");
```

**The Output:**

[image: Output of script]

Comment: It *is* ordered, as a string, “like a dictionary”. Why not just use a NUMBER output which would have the expected ordering? If needing a string, consider padding like “004”

Answer (score 1):

```
 $true_gap_list_item = DB::select("SELECT 

        FORMAT((sum(a_cost- b_cost)),0) as ab,

        FROM cron_db.misreport_weekly_foodcost_item as mwfi
        WHERE mwfi.storeid IN(".$converted_selected_store.") AND year(mwfi.date) = year(subdate(curdate(),1))
        order by (sum(a_cost- b_cost)) DESC");
```